# Custom section is ignored on Magento 2

Tags: cache, magento-2.2.5, section

I am trying to create a custom section with private content to not cached. I follow this article:

https://webkul.com/blog/sections-magento-2/

I did the first two steps:

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_price_region" xsi:type="string">Morwi\PrecioRegional\CustomerData\CustomPriceRegion</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**CustomPriceRegion.php**

```
<?php
namespace Morwi\PrecioRegional\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

class CustomPriceRegion implements SectionSourceInterface
{
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function getSectionData(){
        return [
            'msg' =>'Data from section',
        ];
    }
}
?>
```

After that, the article said I should see the new section of the local storage of the browser, but I don´t see it. How is it set? Is something additional to do?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem did you find any answer?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see customsection from example link after adding to module etc/frontend/di.xml and CustomSection.php

I also check your example and its working only when I change your class CustomPriceRegion to CustomSection (filename also and logout everywhere to check)

even when I stay with name custom_price_region its showing customsection in browser.

Maybe try to finish rest of steps in tutorial.